# Create a pdf A4 size from using PHP script

Tags: php

I have tried to use the php script to generate PDF with a simple programme Hello World. I came across following error which I am unable to understand can someone help?

**SCRIPT**

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');

$pdf=new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

**ERROR:-**

```
Warning: include(helveticab.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\fpdf.php on line 541

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'helveticab.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\fpdf.php on line 541
FPDF error: Could not include font metric file
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure there is the file `helveticab.php` inside `C:\xampp\php\PEAR`

I believe you can download it here: http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/1412.html

Comment: thanks i have this font in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\fpdf\font but still gives me the error

Comment: did you read me? you need to put helevaticab.php here `C:\xampp\php\PEAR` !

Comment: oops thanks I did that but the error is: FPDF error: Undefined font: helveticab B

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to give a look to TCPDF ( http://www.tcpdf.org/ ) which is far better than FPDF also because it is actively developed.

In TCPDF for example you can add fonts by creating them: http://www.tcpdf.org/fonts.php

Comment: +1, Switched over about a year ago from fpdf to tcpdf. Never once looked back.